# Android Studio adds white background to PNG image. How to fix it?

Tags: android, png

I have a PNG logo file that I want to display inside navigation drawer. But whenever I add the image asset to "mipmap", it adds white background and bounding boxes around the image. How to fix this?

Original Image:

[image]

After adding as image asset to Android Project's "mipmap" folder:

[image]

Comment: `mipmap` should only contain the app-icon, not generic graphical resources.

Comment: Where should I place this Navigation Drawer header icon?

Comment: in the `drawable` folders, obviously.

Comment: After place it inside the drawable with icon-type as Action Bar and Tab Icons, the image becomes grey. But if I save it as Launcher Icon in Drawable, the bounding box and white background remains.

Comment: ... `with icon-type`?? PNG and there you go! Android doesn't handle `*.ico files`!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'mipmap' folder used ONLY be used for App icons. And these icons HAVE to have the same width and height. If they aren't, Android Studio will add extra white space to them.

Create a new icon that is square, but simply make some of the image transparent. Then you'll get your desired effect.

Answer (score 1):

It is because the **Shape** property was set to Square by default. I changed it **None**, its fixed now. Thanks for responses.

Answer (score 0):

Run the app - if it still shows - use PhotoShop to make the png.. your  png is not made correcty

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you add it as an image asset as launcher icon it adds white background to the image sometimes if the image isn't of the specified size. Use this option only when you're adding launcher icon, use action bar and tab icons option that won't add any white background to the image, select the theme holo_light theme will make the image dark, and holo_dark theme will make the image white, don't worry you can change the color of image of any custom color by selecting the custom theme while uploading or, you can use the android:tint attribute in the layout file. And add app related graphics in the drawable folder only.